# Lua protobuf library with "oneof" support

Tags: lua, protocol-buffers, openresty

I am looking for Lua-protobuf binding that supports all protobuf syntax like `oneof`. I tried a couple of available libraries but they don't support `oneof`. I will use it in openresty.

Comment: please search the web for things like that.

Comment: I already did and couldn't find anything. Most of the available binding doesn't support "oneof"

Comment: Fwiw I think the question has validity - but if the existing Lua libs don't support oneof, have you considered forking them? I don't know enough about Lua to comment on how hard it is to implement oneof there, but I've implemented it in .NET without too much pain. A list of many of the libs (including at least 3 for Lua) is here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md